# Why does H2O import_file fail with col_names argument?

Tags: import, h2o

It is a strange error when I use the `col_names=` argument in `h2o.import_file`. However, setting the column names by a separate line works fine.

```
import os
import h2o

h2o.init() # It shows H2O_cluster_version 3.36.1.2 and Python version 3.9.7 final

os.system("wget https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/ijcnn1.tr.bz2")
os.system("bzip2 -d ijcnn1.tr.bz2")

# These lines work
col_names = ['class'] + ['F' + str(i) for i in range(22)]
df1 = h2o.import_file(path="ijcnn1.tr")
df1.columns = col_names

# But this line does not work
df2 = h2o.import_file(path="ijcnn1.tr", col_names=col_names)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_20191/3817572867.py in <module>
----> 1 df2 = h2o.import_file(path="ijcnn1.tr", col_names=col_names)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in import_file(path, destination_frame, parse, header, sep, col_names, col_types, na_strings, pattern, skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    498         return lazy_import(path, pattern)
    499     else:
--> 500         return H2OFrame()._import_parse(path, pattern, destination_frame, header, sep, col_names, col_types, na_strings,
    501                                         skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    502 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h2o/frame.py in _import_parse(self, path, pattern, destination_frame, header, separator, column_names, column_types, na_strings, skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    459             path = os.path.abspath(path)
    460         rawkey = h2o.lazy_import(path, pattern)
--> 461         self._parse(rawkey, destination_frame, header, separator, column_names, column_types, na_strings,
    462                     skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    463         return self

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h2o/frame.py in _parse(self, rawkey, destination_frame, header, separator, column_names, column_types, na_strings, skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    476                na_strings=None, skipped_columns=None, custom_non_data_line_markers=None, partition_by=None, quotechar=None,
    477                escapechar=None):
--> 478         setup = h2o.parse_setup(rawkey, destination_frame, header, separator, column_names, column_types, na_strings,
    479                                 skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    480         return self._parse_raw(setup)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py in parse_setup(raw_frames, destination_frame, header, separator, column_names, column_types, na_strings, skipped_columns, custom_non_data_line_markers, partition_by, quotechar, escapechar)
    872                     % (len(column_names), parse_column_len))
    873         else:
--> 874             if len(column_names) != len(j["column_types"]): raise ValueError(
    875                 "length of col_names should be equal to the number of columns: %d vs %d"
    876                 % (len(column_names), len(j["column_types"])))

ValueError: length of col_names should be equal to the number of columns: 23 vs 22
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is bug (off-by-one error) in the SVMLight parser, so I filed a bug [here](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8728).  For now, I'd recommend just naming the columns after you import the file.  Thank you for the reproducible example and bug report!